# Tensorflow Keras plotting graph that incorporates all layers of subclass model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, plot, deep-learning

I want to be able to visualise the full graph for the network I am constructing using subclasses like this:

```
class Resblockchain(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_res_blocks, first_resblock_in_channels, **kwargs):
        super(Resblockchain, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_res_blocks = num_res_blocks
        self.first_resblock_in_channels = first_resblock_in_channels
        self.resblocks_out_channels = self.first_resblock_in_channels // 2
        self.resblocks_inner_dim = self.first_resblock_in_channels // 8

        # Create a dictionary of ResNet blocks
        self.res_blocks = {}
        self.res_blocks['res0'] = ResBlock(self.first_resblock_in_channels,
                                           self.resblocks_out_channels,
                                           temp_kernel_size=1,
                                           stride=1,
                                           dim_inner=self.resblocks_inner_dim)
        self.res_blocks['res1'] = ResBlock(self.resblocks_out_channels,
                                           self.resblocks_out_channels,
                                           temp_kernel_size=3,
                                           stride=1,
                                           dim_inner=self.resblocks_inner_dim)

        for i in range(2, self.num_res_blocks, 2):
            self.res_blocks[f'res{i}'] = ResBlock(self.resblocks_out_channels,
                                                  self.resblocks_out_channels,
                                                  temp_kernel_size=1,
                                                  stride=1,
                                                  dim_inner=self.resblocks_inner_dim)
            self.res_blocks[f'res{i+1}'] = ResBlock(self.resblocks_out_channels,
                                                    self.resblocks_out_channels,
                                                    temp_kernel_size=3,
                                                    stride=1,
                                                    dim_inner=self.resblocks_inner_dim)



    def call(self, inputs):
      x = inputs
      for i in range(self.num_res_blocks):
          x = self.res_blocks[f'res{i}'](x)
      return x

class Monkeynet(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, n_paths=1):
        super(Monkeynet, self).__init__()
        self.n_paths = n_paths
        in_channels = input_shape[-1] // n_paths

        #Equivalent to shallownet below

        self.inputs_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)

        self.conv1 = layers.Conv3D(256, (5, 7, 7), strides=(1, 2, 2), padding='same')
        self.bn1 = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.relu1 = layers.Activation('relu')
        self.max_pool1 = layers.MaxPooling3D((1, 3, 3), strides=(1, 2, 2))
        #end of shallow net, beginning of resblockchain (onepath equivalent)
        self.path1 = Resblockchain(num_res_blocks=10, first_resblock_in_channels=in_channels)
        if n_paths == 2:
          self.path2 = Resblockchain(num_res_blocks=10, first_resblock_in_channels=in_channels)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.max_pool1(x)
        if self.n_paths ==1:
          x = self.path1(x)
        elif self.n_paths==2:
          x1 = self.path1(x)
          x2 = self.path2(x)
          x = layers.concatenate([x1, x2], axis=-1)

        return x

    def build_graph(self):
        x = Input(shape=(5, 64, 64, 256))
        return Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))


Monkeynet_2p = Monkeynet(input_shape=(5, 64, 64, 256), n_paths=2)
Monkeynet_2p.build_graph().summary(expand_nested=True)
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    Monkeynet_2p.build_graph(),                     
    to_file='model.png', dpi=96,              
    show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, 
    expand_nested=False                       
)
```

I would like that when I call model_plot (or any other visualisation recommendations you might have), I not only see a resblockchain node as in here [only shows the resblockchain node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzhAw.png). But actually be able to see each of the blocks that make up the chain.

I have tried an approach inspired by prerakmody in this post, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31647. They seemed to have a similar problem and solved it by moving all the elements to plot into the call() of the main model being plotted,  a bit like so:

```
class Resblockchain(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_res_blocks, first_resblock_in_channels, **kwargs):
        super(Resblockchain, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_res_blocks = num_res_blocks
        self.first_resblock_in_channels = first_resblock_in_channels
        self.resblocks_out_channels = self.first_resblock_in_channels // 2
        self.resblocks_inner_dim = self.first_resblock_in_channels // 8

        # Create a dictionary of ResNet blocks
        self.res_blocks = {}
        self.res_blocks['res0'] = ResBlock(self.first_resblock_in_channels,
                                           self.resblocks_out_channels,
                                           temp_kernel_size=1,
                                           stride=1,
                                           dim_inner=self.resblocks_inner_dim)
        self.res_blocks['res1'] = ResBlock(self.resblocks_out_channels,
                                           self.resblocks_out_channels,
                                           temp_kernel_size=3,
                                           stride=1,
                                           dim_inner=self.resblocks_inner_dim)

        for i in range(2, self.num_res_blocks, 2):
            self.res_blocks[f'res{i}'] = ResBlock(self.resblocks_out_channels,
                                                  self.resblocks_out_channels,
                                                  temp_kernel_size=1,
                                                  stride=1,
                                                  dim_inner=self.resblocks_inner_dim)
            self.res_blocks[f'res{i+1}'] = ResBlock(self.resblocks_out_channels,
                                                    self.resblocks_out_channels,
                                                    temp_kernel_size=3,
                                                    stride=1,
                                                    dim_inner=self.resblocks_inner_dim)



    def call(self, inputs):
        x = inputs
        res_0 = self.res_blocks[f'res{0}'](x)
        res_1 = self.res_blocks[f'res{1}'](res_0)
        res_2 = self.res_blocks[f'res{2}'](res_1)
        res_3 = self.res_blocks[f'res{3}'](res_2)
        res_4 = self.res_blocks[f'res{4}'](res_3)
        res_5 = self.res_blocks[f'res{5}'](res_4)
        res_6 = self.res_blocks[f'res{6}'](res_5)
        res_7 = self.res_blocks[f'res{7}'](res_6)
        res_8 = self.res_blocks[f'res{8}'](res_7)
        res_9 = self.res_blocks[f'res{9}'](res_8)
        
        return res_0, res_1, res_2, res_3, res_4, res_5, res_6, res_7, res_8, res_9
  class Monkeynet(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, n_paths=1):
        super(Monkeynet, self).__init__()
        self.n_paths = n_paths
        in_channels = input_shape[-1] // n_paths

        #Equivalent to shallownet below

        self.inputs_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)

        self.conv1 = layers.Conv3D(256, (5, 7, 7), strides=(1, 2, 2), padding='same')
        self.bn1 = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.relu1 = layers.Activation('relu')
        self.max_pool1 = layers.MaxPooling3D((1, 3, 3), strides=(1, 2, 2))
        #end of shallow net, beginning of resblockchain (onepath equivalent)
        self.path1 = Resblockchain(num_res_blocks=10, first_resblock_in_channels=in_channels)
        if n_paths == 2:
          self.path2 = Resblockchain(num_res_blocks=10, first_resblock_in_channels=in_channels)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.max_pool1(x)
        if self.n_paths ==1:
          res_0, res_1, res_2, res_3, res_4, res_5, res_6, res_7, res_8, res_9 = self.path1(x)
          x = res_9
        elif self.n_paths==2:
          res_01, res_11, res_21, res_31, res_41, res_51, res_61, res_71, res_81, res_91 = self.path1(x)
          x1 = res_91
          res_02, res_12, res_22, res_32, res_42, res_52, res_62, res_72, res_82, res_92 = self.path2(x)
          x2 = res_92
          x = layers.concatenate([x1, x2], axis=-1)

        return x

    def build_graph(self):
        x = Input(shape=(5, 64, 64, 256))
        return Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))
```

which sort of worked to be able to print all the information from the resblocks, but the plot looked strange:[rather than doing a chain of blocks it just gives all sideways](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh7zw.png)

Thanks in advance for the help. Monkeynet is not even the final model, it will just be another submodel of the final model. I would like to ultimately have a way to visualise the entire architecture, even the layers inside the resblocks -- but this would go a long way to help me figure out how to deal with this in subclassing structures. I am trying to replicate and ultimately expand on a scientific paper and keeping the modular structure is important to help me combine, test and train new architectures with ease.